# RTF with background images to PDF

Tags: .net, asp.net, pdf, pdf-generation, rtf

I have a bunch of letters in RTF format. These letters are just a single page and have a background image with text above it. My application opens the RTF as plain text, replace some text fields, and then I want to export it to PDF and sent it by email.

We have tried with a component named TallPDF, but it puts the image in one page, and the text in the other. I am trying to find a component that export the RTF to PDF keeping the original single page format, and I was wondering if any of you fine StackOverflow users has been in the same situation before, and what component would you recomend?

If RTF to PDF is not suitable, any other way to edit the document from .NET easily and export it to PDF ?

Basically the letters are like the X-mas letters:

[image: xmas letter]

Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best bulletproof solution so far:

http://erionpc.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/soa-docx-pdf-report-generation-p2/

Well, apparently the problem is MS Word (surprise?). If you save a Word document as .RTF, even Word Pad is unable to get it right if there are complex designs or elements. So probably MS Word is embedding data that only it understand (surprise!). So the only bulletproof solution is having the MS Word installed, use a PDF printer.

Cheers.